# How to make the increment when two rectangles intersect predictable?

Tags: java, increment, intersect

Long story short, I'm making a racing game in Java. I'm self-taught using some books and my knowledge of math logic and I've only been programming for three weeks so I'm still learning the ins and outs of it all. Here's some background:

I've got a player image surrounded by a bounding rectangle and the code will check to see when that player rectangle intersects a rectangle that is the finish line. Each time it successfully intersects the line, p1Laps gets incremented. When the value reaches a certain point, the game is over and the player is declared the winner.

Here's the problem and the questions:
My problem is that Java is counting multiple intersects each time the rectangles cross. Usually 8 intersects so p1Laps gets incremented 8 times. This would not be a problem if it happened consistently, but sometimes the laps increment at different values. I've encountered increments of 4,7, and 8 so it's hard to set a value to ensure that the race will end after a certain number of laps.

My first question is "why?" Why is java counting so many intersects when the two rectangles cross? I'm assuming it has something to do with them both being 2D shapes, but I could be wrong.

My second question is how to make the increments happen at a consistent value? Preferably "1" but that is not paramount as I can just adjust the finishing value.

Here is the code that seems relevant (a lot of code is removed):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class RacerDoom extends JFrame {
//lap counter
int p1Laps=0;

//bouding rectangles
Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,HEIGHT/2,WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);
Rectangle finishtop = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,(HEIGHT/2)-HEIGHT/9,(int)((WIDTH/9)*1.5),HEIGHT/70);

//check for intersect
if(p1.intersects(finishtop)&&p1Direction==UP){
                        p1Laps++;}
//choose winner
if(p1Laps>=24) {
                        if(!winnerChosen) {
                            winnerChosen = true;
                            break;
}
}
```

As stated, the increments usually go up by 8, but I've had them go by 7 for (seemingly) no reason and they go up by only 4 if "Boost" is enabled (doubles the speed of player).
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is probably that it takes a few frames for the car to move across the finish line. You can solve this by keeping track of whether each car already has intersected the finish line. Use a `boolean` variable for each car, e.g.

```
boolean p1IsOnFinishLine = false;
boolean p2IsOnFinishLine = false;
```

Modify your `if` to check whether the car intersects the finish line *and* `p1IsOnFinishLine` is `false` - this means that it is the first frame in which the car hits the line. If so, increase `p1Laps` *and* set `p1IsOnFinishLine` to `true`. Now, in the next frame, the car will still intersect the finish line, but since `p1IsOnFinishLine` is `true`, you know that you already have counted that lap, so you don't need to do it again. When the car no longer intersects the finish line, you can set `p1IsOnFinishLine` to `false`, so that you're ready for the next crossing.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't considered the frame issue at all. I will implement this ASAP.

Comment: +1 This indeed the best way to do so. This allows you to position the finish line every orientation you like.

Comment: @Speakr In addition to this, you may also want to have "checkpoints", or at least one checkpoint somewhere else on the course to prevent someone from backing up over the finish line counting as an other lap.

Comment: @Speakr: Good to hear it. As you gain more experience with programming, you will find this kind of approach very useful; it is a special case of the more general _state machine_ approach: each object is, at any time, in one of several _states_ (in this case, there are only two states: "currently crossing the finish line" and "not currently crossing the finish line"), and deciding what to do (and which state to go to) based on what state it is currently in.

Comment: @John I have an invisible line that stretches a relevant distance that removes a lap if it is passed over in reverse.
EDIT: Rectangle, not line

Comment: Just implemented this and ran a test. Everything works wonderfully. Thanks again so much for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The player is indeed intersecting the finish line for multiple frames. Each update, you check if it **is** intersecting. This means you are for 8 frames long intersecting with the finish line. What I suggest is to change the way of checking for crossing the line.

- Use a line instead of a rectangle as finish line. This doesn't mean you can't keep it as a rectangle on the screen.
- Use a checking system like:
  *If (player is before line AND next frame the player will be after the finish line)* then lap++

  Something like (supposing you are racing from down to top):

  ```
  if (p1.y > finishLineY && p1.y + speedY < finishLine) lap++;
  ```

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. The only reason I chose Aasmund's response is because with this I think I would have to change all the rectangles to Rectangle2D to check for the intersection with a line.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers tell you where the problem lies.

However, one easy way to figure this out it to try to debug it.  You will be writing the Java code in an IDE (Integrated Development Environment).  Generally, they come with a debugger.  You can use the debugger to set a break point.  When you run the code in debug mode and the code reaches that exact line where the breakpoint is, it will pause and the debugger will take you to your code.  You can then see what's going on.  You will be able to view the variables, like p1Laps.  You can then run the code line by line.  Inspecting the behavior, it will tell you a lot about the code and often you can detect the problem immediately.

Comment: Thanks! I use Eclipse IDE and I've just started tinkering with the Debugger, but this is super informative on the advantages of it. It will definitely become common practice for me.

Comment: Good advice. Also, one can often do without the debugger, simply by using `System.out.println()` to print relevant information.